# Marionette.js appRouter not firing on app start

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am currently integrating Marionette into an existing Backbone application.

I have an existing Backbone router in place, but am trying to implement a Marionette.AppRouter to take its place. The problem is that on a "Hard Refresh" on the url that the new Marionette router should pick up, it does not fire. If I navigate to another page, then go back to the url that did not fire on a hard refresh, it fires correctly. I cannot figure out why it works *after* I have navigated to another page and back again. Here is my code sample:

```
TestApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
    var testAppController = {
        testLoadPage: function(){
            console.log('testLoadPage Fired'); //<---- DOES NOT FIRE ON HARD REFRESH
        }
    };
    TestAppRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({          
        appRoutes: {
            "!/:var/page": "testLoadPage",
            "!/:var/page/*path": "testLoadPage"
        },
        controller: testAppController,
        route: function(route, name, callback) {
            return Backbone.Router.prototype.route.call(this, route, name, function() {
                if (!callback) callback = this[name];
                this.preRoute();
                this.trigger.apply(this, ['beforeroute:' + name].concat(_.toArray(arguments)));
                callback.apply(this, arguments);
            });
        },
        preRoute: function() {
            app.showLoader(name, arguments);
        }
    });
    TestApp.addRegions({
        contentContainer: '#container'
    });
    TestApp.addInitializer(function(options){
        new TestAppRouter();
    });
    TestApp.start();
```

When I load the page: `http://mysamplesite.com/#!/123/page` directly, the Marionette router does not fire as it should.

However, if I load the page: `http://mysamplesite.com/#!/123` and then navigate to `http://mysamplesite.com/#!/123/page`, the Marionette router fires correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you call `Backbone.history.start()` after creating your router instance? If not, you need to do that. Routers won't run until this is called in your app, and you can't call this until at least one route has been instantiated. I usually do this:

```
TestApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
  if (Backbone.history){ Backbone.history.start(); }
});
```

hth

Comment: Yes, I do have `Backbone.history.start` called. I have tried calling it at the beginning of the sample code block, after the sample code block and I just tried your method at the end of the sample code block to no avail. The `console.log('testLoadPage');` still does not fire. Thank you for your response, however the issue still exists.

Comment: I am also noticing that the fix in your response never fires. I added the code: `TestApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
   if (Backbone.history){
    console.log('startingHistoryAgain')
    Backbone.history.start();
   } else (
    console.log('not started again')
   )
  });` and neither the if or the else is ever fired. @Derick Bailey

Comment: be sure the "initialize:after" event is bound before you call `TestApp.start();`

Comment: Thank you so much. my problem has been solved. I can now move forward using Marionette in my application. @Derick Bailey