# Backbone/Marionette Routing for non-root page

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

We have multiple single-page-apps in the same MVC application.  We are using Backbone/Marionette, and routing does not seem to be working (the default Route action is never fired).

The code:

> ```
> QaApp.module("QaApp", function (Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
>     QaApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
>         {
>             appRoutes: {
>                 '' : 'subscribe',
>                 ':id': 'subscribe',
>                 '/qa/index/:id': 'subscribe'
>             }
>         });
>
>     var Api = {
>         subscribe: function (id) {
>             //never fires
>             console.log("subscribing with id = " + id);
>             QaApp.Lightstreamer.Do('subscribeUpdate', {
>                 adapterName: 'QaAdapter',
>                 field: ['jsonString', 'firstData'],
>                 parameterValue: id,
>                 onUpdate: load
>             });
>         },
>         load: function (data) {
>             var question = new QaApp.Question({ id: data.id, collection: data.messages });
>             var questionView = new QaApp.QuestionView(question);
>             QaApp.page.show(questionView);
>         }
>     };
>
>     QaApp.addInitializer(function () {
>         var router = new QaApp.Router(
>         {
>             controller: Api
>         });
>         console.log(router.appRoutes);
>     });
> });
> ```

The standard router seems to assume your root url is `http://localhost` or that, if it isn't, the routes are anything after a # (not finding good documentation, in any case).

So, for us, when you land on the page, the url might be:

`http://localhost/qa/index/1` where the controller is "qa", the view is "index" and the id is 1.

I want my "subscribe" action to fire on this default url and to take the "id" as a parameter.

What route should I be using?

NOTE:  per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260488/marionette-js-approuter-not-firing-on-app-start), I have verified that Backbone.history.start() is called after the initializer runs.

Also NOTE:  under appRoutes are all the different routes I have tried.  I know I need only one, if only I could find the right one.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:  Stepping through the backbone code, it appears that "this.handlers" is an empty array, so it seems like the url can never match.

UPDATE based on updated Answer:  passing in a root does make backbone recognize that I'm at the root, so I'm much closer, but in the following segment, "fragment" is "", this.handlers is a 0 length array, and "matched" returns false:

```
loadUrl: function (fragmentOverride) {
            var fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragmentOverride);
            var matched = _.any(this.handlers, function (handler) {
                if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
                    handler.callback(fragment);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return matched;
        }
```

FINAL UPDATE:  handlers being empty was the problem, and that turned out to be due to a partial on the page loading a second instance of backbone.js - so one instance had handlers set and the other did not

Thanks, David!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to have "#" in your URLs, you need to use pushState with

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true });
```

Note that for this to work, each URL that your Backbone application can generate MUST exist on the server. In other words, the server has to return a valid page to your app for each URL it can reach. The content doesn't have to be different for each URL (you can send the same `index.html` content containing your app and let Backbone handle what should be displayed), but something needs to be sent to the client.

Edit based on comment:

The reason it's not acting as expected is because whatever page you use to start a Backbone application will by default be its root URL, so no routing gets executed. Try setting the `root` attribute when starting the history (see http://backbonejs.org/#History-start)

Comment: Thanks, David.  I actually tried that and it seemed to make no difference.  I'm not opposed to using # in the urls once the page has been loaded.  My issue is that the starting point "http://xxx/qa/index/1" is not being matched to the route "qa/index/:id" and that's what I need to happen.

Comment: Just added an update - stepping into the backbone router, it seems the "handlers" array is always empty, so I am wondering if something is going wrong between marionette and backbone (i.e., I have not set it up properly).  I have essentially copied this bit from Derek's book, so not sure why it wouldn't work, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Thanks - many apologies for being a pain.  Updated after following your edit.  Closer, but something is still missing. Very much appreciate the input.