# Backbone Marionette is not firing routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm creating a simple application using Backbone and Marionette. It's just to fetch a list of Wordpress posts (using an API) and display it.
It's a very simple app so it's not modularized.

I have the following (it's all placed in the same file):

```
if ( Backbone.history )
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false });

if ( Backbone.history.fragment === '' )
    API.listAllPosts();
else
    API.listSinglePost( Backbone.history.fragment );


// Is not firing anything from here...
MyBlog.Router =  Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        '': 'listPosts',
        ':post_name': 'listSingle'
    },
    listPosts: function() {
        console.log('router');
        API.listAllPosts();
    },
    listSingle: function(model) {
        console.log('router, single');
        API.listSinglePost(model);
    }
});
// ...to here

var API = {
    listAllPosts: function() {
        // Fetch all posts and display it. It's working
    },
    listSinglePost: function(model) {
        // Fetch a single post and display it. It's working
    }
}

MyBlog.addInitializer(function() {
    console.log('initializer'); // It's firing

    new MyBlog.Router({
        controller: API
    });
});
```

As [Derick Bailey, Marionette's creator, said](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/) about using triggers on naviagate:

> it encourages bad app design and it is strongly recommended you don’t
>   pass `trigger:true` to `Backbone.history.navigate`.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start the Backbone history before creating the router instance.

Just move that to after the router is created.

```
MyBlog.addInitializer(function() {    
    new MyBlog.Router({ controller: API });

    // should be started after a router has been created
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false });
});
```

The other thing is that the callbacks [should be defined inside of a controller](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.approuter.html#configure-routes) or you should change `appRoutes` to `routes`.

> The major difference between `appRoutes` and `routes` is that we provide
>   callbacks on a controller instead of directly on the router itself.
>   [...]
>   As the `AppRouter` extends `Backbone.Router`, you can also define a `routes`
>   attribute whose callbacks must be present on the `AppRouter`.

Comment: Thank you @Emile Bergeron! It's navigating back and displaying my post list. The problem was on using appRoutes instead of routes and the way I was calling those.
Thank you anyone for advance!

Answer (score 0):

Move this

```
if ( Backbone.history )
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false });

if ( Backbone.history.fragment === '' )
    API.listAllPosts();
else
    API.listSinglePost( Backbone.history.fragment );
```

after the point where your App gets started or inside an `initialize:after` event handler.

Check this previous question: [Marionette.js appRouter not firing on app start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260488/marionette-js-approuter-not-firing-on-app-start)

Comment: are you using hashes (`#`) in the `href` of your links?

Comment: History.navigate() will works only with links?
Actually I'm not using links. I have a unordered list and each li element has a button which has a click event attached. On click, a function is called then Backbone.History.navigate('proper-link-here').

Comment: I made some changes to use links. Tried with/without # in href attribute and preventDefault() on click event but... Not working. I click on button and the single post is displayed (the URL changes), I click back and the URL changes to / but the single post remains on page instead of display the entire list.

Comment: yeap, Backbone router only works with links or `trigger:true` in your `.navigate()`, but using the `trigger:true` is bad practice most of the time. `Backbone.navigate` only changes the `window.locationhash` without firing any routes.

Comment: Yesterday I made some changes on the project and it's all working now. I'd modularized everything also and it's so much easier to fetch resources and even to understand the code. Thank you for your valuable help!